# Dependency Injection in a Java 7 standalone application

Tags: maven, dependency-injection, java-7

I would like to use dependency injection in a large Java 7 standalone application, but I am not really sure where to start.

I have written a small test application:

```
public class Main {

    @Inject
    MyInterface myInterface;

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        Main m = new Main();
        System.out.println(m.myInterface.getMessage());

    }

}
```

with an interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {

    String getMessage();

}
```

and an interface implementation:

```
@Singleton
public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {

    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

}
```

The `pom.xml` contains one dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This application compiles, but of course, it crashes with a `NPE` when trying to print the message. The injection has not happened.

So, my question are:

1. Can dependency injection be achieved in a Java 7 standalone application?
2. What other dependencies do I have to include to make it work?
3. Does anyone have a simple operational example to share (I could not find any)?

Comment: What's your definition of a standalone application?

Comment: It does not need a webserver/container to run... Java SE...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is not only one way to use dependency injection with Java.

(1) You could for instance use the standard CDI, where the reference implementation is [Weld](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/). There is documentation about [using Weld in a Java SE environment](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#d0e5586), what is probably what you mean by *standalone application*.

You could alternatively also use [Spring Framework](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/), which also supports the common CDI annotation (e.g. `@Inject`). In this case, you will typically create a [`ClasspathXmlApplicationContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources-app-ctx-classpathxml) at the program startup and let Spring manages (create/destroy) all the beans you need.

(2) You current dependencies only imports the API of Java EE. Thus I'm not surprised if you get a `NullPointerException` at the execution. You need to add an implementation (like Weld) or use Spring.

(3) See links above.

Also take a look at [Differences between Java EE 6 CDI Implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270379/differences-between-java-ee-6-cdi-implementations) to get reference about other Java CDI available implementations.